# Populate ListBox using a database in C#

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I have been working with a local database using C# windows forms.  I wanted to know how to populate a listBox (or basically retrieve any particular piece of info from the DB and set it to a variable).  It seems obvious that I would need to use a query to gather a particular piece of info, but i dont know how to do this.

Example:  Person Table has the following columns - ID, FirstName, LastName, Age

How do I populate a ListBox with each persons First Name in the Database?

Kind of like `listBox1.Items.Add(Query: Select FirstName from Person)`
or `string variable1 = (Query: SelectFirstName from Person Where ID = 1);`

Comment: Do not use hardcoded database queries in your code - they lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: You should get in the habit of making things as re-usable/scalable as you can.  As an example, we use a table in our DB to store values for drop downs with key indicators and have a stored procedure that returns the specific values for a drop down using those key indicators.  This allows you to change the values of your drop down without having to recompile your application

Comment: It's hard to explain, but I am not exactly hard-coding the way you think.  The application uses "Profiles" so the data displayed will look different depending on the profile selected.  However, in order to create a profile, a table needs to be updated so it has the profile name.  That way when the application starts up, you can choose from whichever profile you want.  However, I need to be able to access the table. So i need to be able to grab info from a column to save to a variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the database data into a data table and set the following properties:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
// fill the data table 

listBox.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName";
listBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 to 4 steps to do that.
1 - ConnectionString
2 - SQlCommand
3 - DataReader
4 - DataSet

//If you're working on a very big project which requires a bunch of SQL table, the ConnectionString is usually done on the App.Config (Windows Form) or Web.Config (WebForm/MVC).

//For the connection string, please click on the link below for some basic information:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

```
2)
private string sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Age FROM Person WHERE ....."
3)
public SQLReader something
{
return this.DataReader(sql);
}

4)
public Dataset SomeData
{
Dataset data = new DataSet()
try
{
 this.DataAdapter(sql).Fill(data, "Person");
}
 catch
 {
 data = null;
 }
 return data;
}
}
}
```